# Loop MySQL-Query 10 times for each item in array (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a Top-10 list with categories but it doesn't work in the way i want it to. There's an array with a dynamic number (n) of items and want to loop each item in this array 10 times to write n*10 rows into a MySQL table. ($i also increments the games rank).
If I echo, print_r or var_dump the code it works, but when I try to write it to the MySQL table it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
foreach($titles as $val) {
$query .=  "INSERT INTO charts (game_place, game_name, game_preweek, game_developer, game_release, game_link, game_image, game_category, charts_updated) VALUES (".$i.", '', '', '', '', '', '', '".$val."', '".time()."');";
mysql_query($query);
};
};
```

Does somebody know the answer to my problem?

Comment: Just a heads up mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 its being replaced with mysqli_query() http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What is the error ?

Comment: Also since you're not adding values to each column id probably make my query a bit more concise just so its easier to read `INSERT INTO charts (game_place, game_category, charts_updated) VALUES (".$i.", '".$val."', '".time()."');`

Answer (score 4):

```
$query .=  "INSERT ....`
```

You're adding each new query onto the end of the previous query. That's going to produce invalid SQL after the first iteration. You just need to assign the query as:

```
$query =  "INSERT ....`
```

You should also look at using PDO or mysqli_ instead - this sort of thing is an ideal use for a prepared statement.

Comment: I was just getting ready to post that in the comment to replace `$query .=` with `$query =`

Comment: [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is significantly better than the deprecated `mysql_query` interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO `charts`` (`game_place`, `game_category`, `charts_updated`) VALUES ";
foreach ($titles as $key => $val){
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
        $query .= "(".$i.", '".$val."', ".time()."),";
    }
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -1);//remove last comma
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no, I don't just want the first 10 values. 
I have multiple categories which I saved in an array. Now I want to create 10 (default) entries via SQL for each item in this array.
Like that:
`INSERT INTO 'charts' ('**game_place**', '**game_category**,', 'charts_updated') VALUES ('**1**', '**category_one**', 'JUST_THE_TIME')";`
Repeat this until game_place reached 10 for this category, then do the next 10 INSERTS for the new category
`INSERT INTO 'charts' ('**game_place**', '**game_category**,', 'charts_updated') VALUES ('**1**', '**category_TWO**', 'JUST_THE_TIME')";`

Comment: @ManuelRampp - I think I got it this time. I updated my answer.